# How to properly use transactions with workspaces in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm maintaining an old database that is being used as a front-end for another database. To give a summary of what this front-end is doing, it loops for example 10 times, and calls a subroutine(let's name it Parent) that creates a transaction in the default workspace, then that subroutine calls 5 other subroutines(let's call each of them Child) and if one of them fails, it theoretically rollbacks the transaction, and sets the workspace object to Nothing.

However, I'm not sure this is working every time, or working at all. To find out if it was working properly, I created two test subroutines, one that initiates the transaction(Parent), and calls the child subroutine. Both subroutines are trying to insert data in a dummy table. When I need to initiate the rollback, I raise a custom error from the child subroutine to the parent one. After much experimentation, I noticed that the only time the data was inserted properly, or the transaction made the rollback when I raised the error, was only when I was explicitly closing the workspace object after the rollback and before setting it to Nothing. The only reference I managed to find on this was [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822782.aspx).

As you can understand, I'm confused, because this database has been used as a front-end for many years, and somehow it seems to manage to insert data. I have also seen code examples over the web that none of them are closing the workspace object after commit or rollback of the transaction.

My main concern was that the rollback was not working properly when errors were being raised, so I'm trying to make a better solution.

**Update: Added some test code, showing just the transaction commit**
I will only see changes in the sys_test table if I include the wrk.Close statement. Otherwise, the subroutine will never add data to the table, and the database will need to be restarted, then if I add wrk.Close and run the subroutine again, the changes will be made to the table.

Child subroutine:

```
Public Sub testChildTransaction()
On Error GoTo err
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO sys_test (myName) VALUES ('Child');", dbFailOnError
exit_f:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox "Error from Child"
    Resume exit_f
End Sub
```

Main Subroutine:

```
Public Sub testTransactions()
On Error GoTo err
    Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
    Dim rollback As Boolean
    Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    With wrk
    .BeginTrans
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO sys_test (myName) VALUES ('Parent')", dbFailOnError
        testChildTransaction          
    .CommitTrans
    End With
exit_f:
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rollback Then
        wrk.rollback
        MsgBox "Rollback Achieved"
    End If
    wrk.Close
    Set wrk = Nothing
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox "Error"
    rollback = True
    Resume exit_f
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your question would become clearer if you'd add some code - shortened to the essentials, or pseudocode would help too.

Comment: I have added some sample code. Please ignore the error handling, I've edited most parts of my actual subroutine, so I'm just showing that the transaction won't work without wrk.Close

Comment: I just found this website: http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/using-dao-access-data.html It looks like it's a great source for this kind of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty odd. `DBEngine.Workspaces(0)` is the **default** workspace, and you are not supposed to close it. Normally you only close workspaces that you have opened yourself with `DBEngine.CreateWorkspace`.

Your problems may result from mixing your own workspace variable with `CurrentDb`, which isn't part of your workspace (not really sure about that).

When using the default workspace (either for possible rollback or for performance), I always use a separate database variable, that is defined as "child" of the workspace:

```vb
Dim WS As Workspace
Dim DB As Database

Set WS = DBEngine(0)
Set DB = WS.Databases(0)

WS.BeginTrans

DB.Execute "Stuff"    ' Not CurrentDb 

If "everything ok" Then
    WS.CommitTrans
Else
    WS.Rollback
End If

' With a local WS variable, even this is not necessary, but definitely no WS.Close here!
Set WS = Nothing
```

In your case you'd have to declare `DB` as public variable, or pass it as parameter to `testChildTransaction()`

Comment: While you answer does not address the issue directly, it pointed me to the right direction. Looking at the website I posted above -> http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/the-currentdb-function.html There is enough information about what's going on with the currentDb. Setting it to an object works as expected. :)